# Python subprocess and bash sed yielding: /bin/sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Tags: python, bash

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
import pip
installed_packages = pip.get_installed_distributions()
installed_packages_list = sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version)
    for i in installed_packages])
comms=''.join(installed_packages_list)
filter="sed 's/\,/\n/g' | tr -d '[] ' | sed 's/\x27//g'"
p = subprocess.Popen([filter], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
vtime = p.stdin.write(comms)
print(vtime)
```

I am trying to be tricky and write a binary that I can run to produce a formatted list of the installed Python module versions. The following yields this confusing output:

`None`

`bin/sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string`

Comment: why do you need to pass `filter` within a list given that you're passing `shell=True` to `subprocess.Popen`?

Comment: Why use the shell for basic string manipulation?

Comment: 1_CR, I am trying to avoid formatting errors with Popen.
jordanm, Good question, I know that Python is more than capable of chewing up and spitting out text. I guess this is more of a theory thing. Also, I am having the XY problem for sure.

Comment: Is `print '\n'.join(installed_packages_list)` enough for what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the \x27 is a single quote character that get's interpreted by the python interpreter resulting in early termination of your single quoted string. Try adding extra escapes, something like:

```
filter="sed 's/\,/\n/g' | tr -d '[] ' | sed 's/\\\'//g'"
```

Comment: You can't escape single quotes inside single quotes in the shell. Therefore it should look more like: `'s/'\\'//g'`.

Comment: Actually -- it's a single quote inside double quotes. I tested my code before submitted answer -- I believe it works as posted.